# c# get records which exist in each group ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**Problem: Get users which exists in all entities, like Ali exists in ENT01,ENT02,ENT03**

I have a list I want to get users which exist in each group. In given Image detail `OfficerName`"**Ali**" exist in all three EntityCode. I need to get users which exist in given list of EntityCodes

[image: result set]

List of **EntitUser** retrieved from Database table. using below query

```
List<string> EntityCodes = new List<string>();// have 3 EntCodes, can have more

var Contacts=_db.EntityUser.Where(x => x.MasterGroupCode == GroupCode  && x.IsCurrent==true).ToList();
```

I get a list of `EntityUser` consisting these properties

```
public partial class EntityUser
{
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string EntityCode { get; set; }
        public string OfficerType { get; set; }
        public string OfficerName { get; set; }
}
```

Any Help would be much appricated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly this example should solve your problem.

note: just use your dbContext instead of `EntityUsers` collection

```
// sample test data
var EntityUsers = new List<EntityUser>()
{
    new EntityUser(){EntityCode = "ENT01" , OfficerName = "ali"},
    new EntityUser(){EntityCode = "ENT02" , OfficerName = "ali"},
    new EntityUser(){EntityCode = "ENT03" , OfficerName = "ali"},
    new EntityUser(){EntityCode = "ENT01" , OfficerName= "jorj"},
    new EntityUser(){EntityCode = "ENT01" , OfficerName= "reza"},
    new EntityUser(){EntityCode = "ENT01" , OfficerName= "hamid"},
    new EntityUser(){EntityCode = "ENT01" , OfficerName= "farid"},
    new EntityUser(){EntityCode = "ENT02" , OfficerName= "farid"},
    new EntityUser(){EntityCode = "ENT03" , OfficerName= "sasan"},
    new EntityUser(){EntityCode = "ENT02" , OfficerName= "jorj"},
};

// this also can be load from database.  
List<string> entityCodes = new List<string>() { "ENT01" , "ENT02" , "ENT03" }; 

// linq query to select users that has all EntityCodes
var usersInAllEntities = from u in EntityUsers 
                         group u by u.OfficerName into gr
                         where entityCodes.All(c => gr.Any(g => g.EntityCode == c ) )
                         from usr in gr
                         select usr;
```

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my day. I just had to change result to a List. Thanks again